# How to load updated data from database(mysql) without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to show the data from database into a page.
I am using AJAX and PHP.
But there is not coming new updates data.
If i refresh the page, then it is showing new updates data.
Please give me some idea about it or some links for example.

Thanks advance everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two reason for that either cache or your control will not wait until your response of ajax is come back.
try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<your file url>",
    data: {<arguments>},
    cache: false,
    async:false,
    success: function(data) {

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use jQuery AJAX
[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Some Jquery AJAX tutorials:

[jQuery - AJAX Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

[jQuery - AJAX load() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

[jQuery - AJAX get() and post() Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

[Submit A Form Without Page Refresh using jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

[A simple AJAX website with jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp. You have to use AJAX code as it is. Change get file name as PHP file which you are using.

(Providing the code which you have used helps more.)

Answer (score 0):

this is ajax code for updating result

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

             function search(){

                  var title=$("#search1").val();

                  if(title!=""){
                    $("#result").html("<img alt='ajax search' src='images/loader.gif'/>");
                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"tes.php",////php file that access db data/////
                        data:"title="+title,
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#result").html(data);//.By using<ul id="result"></ul>in area where data has to be updated you can easily make over this.//
                            $("#search1").val("");///name of field through which you going to update//////
                         }
                      });
                  }      
             }

              $("#button").click(function(){
                   search();
              });

              $('#search1').keyup(function(e) {
                 if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                    search();
                  }
              });
        });
```